# rails_admin - destroyed model still showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I've set up a rails 3.1 using rails_admin as a backend.

I created some models, added a few entries using rails_admin and then reailsed that my models were completely incorrect.

I've destroyed the models using

```
rails destroy model Mymodel
```

I've then migrated the database again.

Why are my destroyed models still showing in the rails_admin dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used rails_admin but...

destroy only deletes the files which were created on the generate but doesn't create a migration to remove the database table.

I imagine you've still got the database table hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

Do a pull on the DB if it is remote and take the records out